# What to do If I can't assign Future functions to onPressed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, onpress

I have a proplem in assigning a sign in future method to onpressed :The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.

Comment: Can you please add your tried code?

Comment: It was solved but thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to assign it like this:

```
onpressed: () => FunctionName()
```

Because the handler expects a function with no return. So we just call your function inside an anonymous void function.

Comment: Ok Thanks but one last thing ?

Comment: Sure, what is it?

Comment: A TextEditingController can't be assigned to type String.

Comment: and I want to sign in with email and password from a text field

Comment: @OmarYacop You have to look at the function and see what it is expecting to get, and then pass that. I think you'd really benefit from going through some tutorials on the basics of Flutter/Dart, here is a good basics course video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0uinJvhNxI

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code snippet

```
onPressed:(){
// To do 
CustomFunction();
}
```